# How can we generate static HTML files from JSP during the build process of our Maven app

Tags: java, html, maven, jsp, gulp

We have a fairly old Maven web app and I have been tasked with optimizing the front-end. I have found that we have hundreds of unused style rules in our CSS (Which is generated from LESS). We have begun to implement Gulp into our apps build process and I would like to implement a task that removes all unused style rules from our CSS. This should drastically reduce the size of the CSS files we serve up. The problem I have is that this task requires the CSS and HTML files. As this is a JSP app the HTML is generated when a user makes a request for that page, not during the build process. This means I don't have the static HTML files that this task needs.

The plugin I was planning on using is:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss

I was hoping that we could add a build step that generates static HTML files that we could then use in the Gulp task to remove the unused CSS rules, then run another Gulp task that deletes these files.

Comment: You can't, because this is a JSP app and the HTML is generated when a user makes a request for that page

Comment: I realize that as I have said in the above explanation. I'm asking if there is a way to generate them at all? Within the Maven build process or even within Gulp? If there really is no way, are there any other ways you know of to remove all of the unused styles? (Doing this manually is not a practical option). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP is a dynamic, you never know what is generated from JSP page. It's absolutely dynamic templating engine that compiles to a servlet not html. This servlet writes to the response out a text used by the template.

So, you can't use Gulp on server side using JSP as an endpoint or a servlet retured that JSP.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

By nature JSP is dynamic, so you cannot generate static pages from them.

One potential option is to manually visit each page in a browser and retrieve the generated HTML, but this would be time consuming and has issues.

Consider:

```
<c:if test="${something eq true}">
    <div style="styleOne"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${something eq false>
    <div style="styleTwo"/>
</c:if>
```

You'd need to be sure you're not accidentally omitting classes.

What I might do in this situation is use a script to get a list of classes in use. It's still going to be time consuming. You can use something as simple as `ack` to get a list of all uses of `class="someClass"` in the project. For example:

```
ack 'class=".*"'
```

This will print out each use of `class=` in the whole project. From there, you can filter that or just refine the regex to only print the contents inside the class attribute.

As for verifying IDs, that will be more time consuming, but hopefully they are not too prevalent. I would use `ack` again, but replace `class` with `id`. Then I'd use a similar query for CSS.

```
ack --type=css "#.*{"
```

This will find each use of an ID in your CSS files. Then I'd cross reference those with the previously gained ID list. Any IDs that exist in the CSS output but not in the `id=".*"` query can safely be removed.